# How to edit a TextView in a fragment from MainActivity

Tags: android-studio

I have a textview in a fragment that I want to edit in MainActivity.java (The parent activity). I've tried many methods such as creating a function in the fragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return root;
    }

    public void status(String txt){
        TextView textView = getView().findViewById(R.id.status_message);
        textView.setText(txt);
    }
}
```

and calling it in MainActivity like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragment.status("Test");
    }
}
```

But this results in the app crashing. How can I fix this? I am using the Bottom Navigation Activity Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by accessing MainActivity from the fragment rather than accessing Fragment from MainActivity. Instead of changing the textview from MainActivity, send the string you want to put in the textview through a method and change the textview in the fragment.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    String text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public String sendData(){
        return text;
    }

}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        tv = root.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        MainActivity ma = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        tv.setText(ma.sendData());
        return root;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing I would advice is to create your fragment instance in your main activity like this:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        HomeFragment fragment = 
HomeFragment.createInstance("Test");
    }
}
```

And then in your fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private string text;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater 
inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, 
container, false);
       TextView textView = 
      root.findViewById(R.id.status_message);
        return root;
    }

  public static HomeFragment createInstance(String text)  
  {
     HomeFragment f =new HomeFragment ();
     Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("key", text);
     f.set arguments(bundle);
     return f;
 }

@Override
 public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle 
savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments != null) {
          text= getArguments.getString("key");
          status(text);
    }
    
}

public void status(String txt){
      textView.setText(txt);
 }
}
```

Hopes this helps

Comment: This doesn't crash the program but it does not change the textview either. I think its because the onCreate function is run before the Bundle is passed to it, so no changes are made

Comment: Sorry this is coming late, you can try putting it on onViewCrrated

Comment: Already tried, didn't work either. I also tried constantly checking for new bundles using AsyncTask which didn't seem to work either.

Comment: I fixed this problem on my own. Thank you for your help.